# Three.js: Reflection on ground. How it works?

Tags: 3d, three.js, render

I want something like this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pagenstecher.de](http://static.pagenstecher.de/uploads/7/7c/7c3/7c34/abt-sportsline-audi-rs-faked2.jpg))</sub>

And I tried it with cubeCamera, but it seems to work only with cubes, spheres and so on, but on a plane as a ground with a character on it, the reflection looks broken.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

1) Set the floor to be translucent. `material.opacity = 0.5;`

2) Place a Mirror just below the floor.

*Mirror Example* : http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html

Comment: Reflector worked great. I was using cubeCam before but Reflector is more realtistic

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to fake reflection is to duplicate the object under a translucent plane. One example is http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_text.html